# Assert that string has a required ending

Tags: c#

In C# I would like to check whether a string ends with `*.js`.The string is the name of a file and I want to know if the file is JavaScript or not.

So far, I only found this way of doing it:

```
Assert.IsTrue(Regex.Matches(myFilename, "*.js").Count != 0);
```

To me, this seems a bit backhanded because I need to count the number of occurrences rather than just checking if there is one.

Also, the code fails with this error:

```
Message: System.ArgumentException : parsing "*.js" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.
```

Any idea what could be wrong with the code?

What is the simplest way to assert that a string is in accordance with a given regex?

Comment: How about just `myFilename.EndsWith(".js")`?

Comment: @Liam That's not a good dupe target

Comment: Yeah, I (now) agree. Sure there is a duplicate though

Comment: It's hard to find an appropriate dupe target because this question is so basic, everyone just types "c# string ends with" in google and the first five answers are the official docs telling you the `string.EndsWith` method exists. Google before asking, you'll save a lot of people (including you) time.

Comment: Not really sure why people are upvoting this question, it certainly doesn't show research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems with your regex are :

1. `*` is special quantifier, it cannot follow nothing (*source of your error*). You mean "I want anything before". In regex, this is `.*`, but in your case you don't even need it ! Regex are not forced to match all the string, just the expression part .
2. `.` is a special character too. It means "any character". You want only an actual dot `.` character, so you have to escape it as well. : `\.`
3. Finally, there is no precision to match the end of string.  `$`

**Correct regex would be either** "`\.js$`" (**or** "`.*\.js$`") instead of "`*.js`" .

---

And anyway, to check if a string ends with a specific substring, you can simply use `string.EndsWith(".js")`, as answered by @Toshi. Probably a much better choice in any aspect.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `EndsWith`

```
Assert.IsTrue(myFilename!=null && myFilename.EndsWith(".js"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the substring function to extract the last three characters of the string and compare whether it is equal to ".js" or not.

Assert.IsTrue(myFile.Substring(myFile.Length-3), ".js" )

---

Apart from it, as already mentioned EndsWith is also an optimal solution.

Comment: If the answer is poor can you give comments so that it can be updated rather than just downvoting it without any explanation. "No explanation" is not gonna help me understand the issue with the answer. :)